# Optimise the creation of a record with many records that belong to it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

#### Description

I'm writing full stack web application using **ReactJS**, **Laravel** and **MySQL** that allows users to **create quizzes**.

#### My database structure:

##### Quizzes table

```sql
create table quizzes (
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    description text null,
    duration smallint unsigned not null,
    is_open tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    shuffle_questions tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    user_id bigint unsigned not null,
    lesson_id bigint unsigned not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint quizzes_lesson_id_foreign foreign key (lesson_id) references lessons (id) on delete cascade,
    constraint quizzes_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id) on delete cascade
) collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

##### Questions table

```sql
create table questions (
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    title text not null,
    description text null,
    image varchar(255) null,
    type enum ('radio', 'checkbox', 'text', 'image') not null,
    is_required tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    points tinyint unsigned default '0' not null,
    quiz_id bigint unsigned not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint questions_quiz_id_foreign foreign key (quiz_id) references webagu_24082021.quizzes (id) on delete cascade
) collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

##### Answers table

```sql
create table answers (
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    value varchar(1024) null,
    is_correct tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    quiz_id bigint unsigned not null,
    question_id bigint unsigned not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint answers_question_id_foreign foreign key (question_id) references questions (id) on delete cascade,
    constraint answers_quiz_id_foreign foreign key (quiz_id) references quizzes (id) on delete cascade
) collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

#### Data that comes from UI when user press "Save quiz" button

```js
//....
axios
    .post('/quizzes', { "quiz": QuizData, "questions": QuestionsData, "answers": AnswersData })
    .then(res => {
        if(201 === res.status) alert('Quiz saved!');
        console.log(res.data)
    });
//....
```

#### Quiz controller `store` method

```php
public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $quizData = $request->input('quiz');
    $questions = $request->input('questions');
    $answers = $request->input('answers');

    $groupedAnswers = Utils::groupBy('_question_id', $answers);

    //DB::beginTransaction();

    $quizData['user_id'] = \auth('api')->user()->id;
    $quiz = Quiz::create($quizData);

    $new_questions = [];
    $new_answers = [];

    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $question['quiz_id'] = $quiz->id;
        $new_question = Question::create($question);
        $new_questions[] = $new_question;

        $qid = $question['_question_id'];

        if (isset($groupedAnswers[$qid])) {
            $question_answers = $groupedAnswers[$qid];

            foreach ($question_answers as $answer) {
                $answer['quiz_id'] = $quiz->id;
                $answer['question_id'] = $new_question->id;

                $new_answer = Answer::create($answer);
                $new_answers[] = $new_answer;
            }
        }
    }

    //DB::commit();

    $resData = ['quiz' => $quiz, 'questions' => $new_questions, 'answer' => $new_answers];

    return response()->json($resData, 201);
}
```

My current code algorithm:

1. Creates `Quiz` object
2. In `foreach` loop assign `Quiz::id` to `Question` object `quiz_id` foreign key column and creates
3. In inner `foreach` loop assign `Question::id` to `Answer` object `question_id` foreign key column and creates

#### Problem

This algorithm creates **Q (questions count) * A (answers count)** SQL queries - and this this very slow.

For example, if quiz contains 50 questions, each have 4 answers variants, query will contain 50 * 4 = 200 SQL queries.

So, how to change this bad solution to make it work faster?

Comment: You can use `DB::insert()`

Comment: Actually you have 251 queries for 1 quiz, 50 questions, 200 answers.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for all answers! They have gotten me useful information and I tried to adapt them for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you have 50 questions, you have:

- `1` query to create a `quiz`
- `50` queries to create `questions`
- `200` queries to create `answers`

**Total : `251` queries.**

---

If I'm not mistaken with your coding, you can optimize your query like this (*example 50 questions, I explain in the comment block*) :

```
$input_quiz      = $request->input('quiz');
$input_questions = $request->input('questions');
$input_answers   = $request->input('answers');
$groupedAnswers  = Utils::groupBy('_question_id', $input_answers);

/*********************/

// Create a quiz (1 query)
$quiz = Quiz::create($input_quiz); 

// Create questions (50 queries)
$questions = $quiz->questions()->createMany($input_questions);

// Prepare answers data
$answers = [];

// Loop $questions
foreach ($questions as $key => $question){

    // If I'm not mistaken, the index on the input 
    // will be equal to $questions (starting at 0)
    $qid = $input_questions[$key]['_question_id'];

    if(isset($groupedAnswers[$qid])){
        $question_answers = $groupedAnswers[$qid];

        // Modify answer
        foreach ($question_answers as $_answer){
            $_answer['quiz_id']     = $quiz->id;
            $_answer['question_id'] = $question->id;
            $_answer['created_at']  = now();    // Laravel insert not saved created_at column
            $_answer['updated_at']  = now();    // Laravel insert not saved updated_at column
            $answers[]              = $_answer; // Push it
        }
    }
}

// Then, we will bulk insert using the insert method (1 query)
$answers = Answer::insert($answers);
```

Now, you have :

- `1` query to create a `quiz`
- `50` queries to create `questions`
- `1` query to create `answers`

**Total : `52` queries.**

---

What I've ever done in a case like this is, use only 3 queries. But many considerations, such as using a temporary column. However, I don't think you need to go that far.

Comment: Eventually, I choosed this answer. But, please, add following code as first statement for `foreach` to `Modify answer` section, as I can't edit it:
```unset($_answer['id']); // this will prevent SQL PRIMARY KEY constraint violation error
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution will result in:

- One query to insert the `Quiz`.
- One query for each `Question`.
- One query per `Question` to insert its `answers` if it has any.

So a maximun of `1 + (questions_count)*2` queries.

If your answers didn't rely on the `question_id` everything could be done in **4 queries**

```
    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        /* ******************************************* */
        //  GETTING AND INSERTING QUIZ
        /* ******************************************* */
        $quizData = $request->input('quiz');
        $quizData['user_id'] = \auth('api')->user()->id;
        $quiz = Quiz::create($quizData);

        /* ******************************************* */
        //  GETTING QUESTIONS AND THEIR ANSWERS
        /* ******************************************* */
        $questions = $request->input('questions');

        $answers = $request->input('answers');
        $answersByQuestion = Utils::groupBy('_question_id', $answers);

        // ***********************************************
        // ***********************************************
        $new_questions = [];
        $new_answers = [];

        foreach ($questions as $question) {
            // $question['quiz_id'] = $quiz->id; $new_question = Question::create($question);
            $new_question = $quiz->questions()->create($question);
            $new_questions[] = $new_question; // FOR THE RESPONSE

            if (isset($answersByQuestion[$question['_question_id']])) {

                // PREPARING ANSWERS FOR BULK INSERT
                foreach ($answersByQuestion[$question['_question_id']] as $answer) {

                    $answer['quiz_id'] = $quiz->id;
                    $answer['question_id'] = $new_question->id;
                    $new_answers[] = $answer;
                }
            }
            DB::table('answers')->insert($new_answers);
        }

        $resData = ['quiz' => $quiz, 'questions' => $new_questions, 'answer' => $new_answers];

        return response()->json($resData, 201);
    }
```

---

## Idea for 4 queries (Ultimate optimization)

I see that:

- you use `_question_id` on the `Answers` to do the link with their `Question`.
- A `Quiz` **has-many** `questions` and `answers`.
- An `Answer` **belong** to one `question` and its one `quiz`.

[image]

So do this.

1. **Create** the `Quiz`.
2. Take the `quiz_id` and **bulk insert** all the `questions` including the new field `_question_id`.
3. **Select** all the `Quiz` `questions`.

- Prepare a nested array that contains all `Answers` and add to each answer the **actual** `question_id` by the help of `_question_id`.

4. **Bulk insert** all the `answers`.

Comment: I think this will save more. If you have 50 questions, you have : 1 quiz, 50 questions, 50 answers. Total 101 queries. CMIIW.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto 101 is correct. but it is the max because I see that he checks if the grouped answers are set for the question. which may imply that he may have questions with no answers so less than 101 queries.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto what do you think about the idea for 4 queries. Is it understandable ?

Comment: Yes I think this makes sense. You can save more queries here. I really appreciate your efforts. But it's up to OP whether he agrees with it or not. #upvoted

Comment: Does `Answers` contain the options for "multiple choice"?  Or are they what users replied with?

Comment: @RickJames each `Answer` has the property `is_correct`. So, I assume that a `Question` may have from one to many valid choices.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, each `Question` can have many correct `Answers`

Answer (score 2):

One Quiz has many Questions.  This 1-to-many relationship is properly handled by `questions.quiz_id`.

Similarly, one Question has many Answers.  This 1-to-many relationship is properly handled by `Answers.question_id`.

But there is a minor no-no -- `Answers.quiz_id` is "redundant" since it can be found via `Questions`.  In proper schema design, that column should not exist.  For only 200 Answers (or even for a million answers) you cannot make a "performance argument".

**Round trips and lots of statements**

If practical, all the quizzes could be inserted in one `INSERT` statement; all the questions in another statement; and all the answers in a third.  (No, I don't know how to do that in Laravel; but I can explain for MySQL.)

Meanwhile, a hundred, perhaps a thousand, queries per second is nothing to worry about.

(As a bonus, "batching" inserts runs about 10 times as fast.)

Comment: You made the case of relational database which 100% correct. But his question is still valid when it comes to the number round trips from the server to the DB.

Comment: Thank you, for Your answer. The problem, for now,  not related to perfomance. The problem, as I said,  it's create huge number of SQL statements.

Comment: @medilies - I added to my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames, can You show example in MySQL?

Comment: @KiazimKhutaba - `INSERT INTO t (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3), (11,22,33), (9,8,7), ...;`